# How to show .phtml content in browser

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created the **new theme** and **new phtml** file in **magento2.1.5**

The file path is `app/design/frontend/demo/static/Magento_Theme/templates/html/staticpage.phtml`

The `staticpage.phtml` file contains static content, I have used the URL http://localhost/magento2/staticpage.phtml but it shows the 404 page.

I want to show this file content in this URL, 
***What are steps and changes needed to show phtml file content***?

Comment: try like http://localhost/magento2/index.php/staticpage.phtml

Comment: It is not working

Comment: you have working on  thewrong way

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not a proper way, you should not call the file directly.

You will need a controller to handle your page and a layout in which you should call the phtml file.

if the controller already exist :

for ex : home page the controller will be **module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php**
and the layout will be **cms_index_index.**

So if you want to display the block on home page :

create following file in your theme :
app/design/frontend/demo/static/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

and write following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="<block/container_in_which_you_want_to_show_your_block>">
            <block class="<the_block_class_you_want_to_use)>" name="<block_name>" template="<your_template_reference_path>"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Sample code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="default_no_route" template="Magento_Cms::html/staticpage.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If the controller does not exist, i.e. you want to show it on a new page.
you need to create a controller and respective layout, router etc,. and use the above code in its layout. Just change referenceContainer tag to container.

Comment: The controller is exist in the path : /vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/

But it is not working.

Comment: So, do you want to display your block on home page. If yes, directly hit the url  http://localhost/magento2/index.php (assuming your magento 2 setup is proper)